# 'status' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: python, django, django-models

I new to Django & Python. (Previously is PHP). I am having problem where I want to arhive custom model without DB blinding. The data for the model is come from raw SQL.

I trying to find out how to get data from rawsql then insert to Object. I found this article [Model Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods) which look promising.

After try & error. I get the error below:

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/a/something
>
> Django Version: 2.1.5 Python Version: 3.7.2 Installed Applications:
>   ['django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth', 
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles', 
>   'rest_framework',  'rest_framework.authtoken',  'phonenumber_field', 
>   'user_accounts',  'shipments',  'CA',  'rest_auth', 
>   'rest_auth.registration',  'allauth',  'allauth.account', 
>   'django.contrib.sites',  'allauth.socialaccount',  'dashboard']
>   Installed Middleware:
>   ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
>
> Traceback:
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\myfxhuta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py"
>   in inner
>     34.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\myfxhuta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\myfxhuta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\myfxhuta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py"
>   in wrapped_view
>     54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\myfxhuta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py"
>   in view
>     68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\myfxhuta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py"
>   in dispatch
>     495.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\myfxhuta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py"
>   in handle_exception
>     455.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\myfxhuta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py"
>   in dispatch
>     492.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\myfxhuta\Documents\Coding\python-testing\CA\dashboard\views.py"
>   in get
>     23.             "data" : consignment_status.objects.with_counts()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\myfxhuta\Documents\Coding\python-testing\CA\dashboard\models.py"
>   in with_counts
>     22.                 p = self.model(consignmentNo=row[0], status=row[1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods), created_time=row[2])
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\myfxhuta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py"
>   in **init**
>     485.                 raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % kwarg)
>
> Exception Type: TypeError at /a/something Exception Value: 'status' is
>   an invalid keyword argument for this function

This is my **models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class list_consignment(models.Manager):


def with_counts(self):
    import pyodbc
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=127.0.0.1;Database=TEST;uid=USERID;pwd=PASSWORD;')
    cursor = cnxn.cursor() 

    with cnxn.cursor()  as cursor:

        cursor.execute("""select t.ConsignmentNo, case when t2.TaskId = '50' then t2.TaskName when t2.TaskId IS NULL then 'NEW' else 'PENDING' end as 'status', case when t2.TaskId IS NOT NULL then t2.ActEnd else t.CreateDate end as created_time from ( select ConsignmentNo,JobEntry.CreateDate,JobEntry.JobStatus, max(ActEnd) as lastes_time from JobEntry left join jobTracking on JobEntry.JobNo = jobTracking.JobNo and JobEntry.companyid=jobTracking.companyid where JobEntry.companyid = 40 and JobEntry.CustomerCode = 'A000177' and ConsignmentNo like '%' and CAST(JobEntry.CreateDate as date) >= CAST(getdate()-1 as date) and JobEntry.iscancel = 0 group by ConsignmentNo, JobEntry.CreateDate,JobEntry.JobStatus ) t left Join ( select ConsignmentNo,JobEntry.CreateDate as jcreate_date, jobTracking.* from JobEntry left join jobTracking on JobEntry.JobNo = jobTracking.JobNo and JobEntry.companyid=jobTracking.companyid where JobEntry.companyid = 40 and JobEntry.BranchId = 40 and CAST(JobEntry.CreateDate as date) >= CAST(getdate()-1 as date) and JobEntry.CustomerCode = 'A000177' and ConsignmentNo like '%' )t2 on t.ConsignmentNo = t2.ConsignmentNo and t.lastes_time = t2.ActEnd and t.CreateDate = t2.jcreate_date order by status, ConsignmentNo""")
        result_list = []
        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            p = self.model(consignmentNo=row[0], status=row[1], created_time=row[2])

            result_list.append(p)
    return result_list

class consignment_status(models.Model):
    consignmentNo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.TextField
    created_time = models.DateField()
    objects = list_consignment()
    class Meta:
            managed = False
```

This is my **view.py**

```
class dashboard(APIView):
    permission_classes=(AllowAny,) 
    def get(APIView, request):

        data = [{
            "data" : consignment_status.objects.with_counts()
        }]

        return HttpResponse(data)
```

Kindly provide guidance what should is the error?

Comment: did you print that `result_list` to see what's actually in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the consignment_status class change,

```
status = models.TextField
```

to

```
status = models.TextField(max_length=100)
```